# How do I enable Eclipse/Java to handle special unicode characters

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, character-encoding

Do not know how to do the following:  Using Java, Eclipse on a MacBook Pro running MacOs Mojave version 10.14 (also PostgreSQL), need to use special characters ç ś ṣ ṇ ṛ Ṇ ṃ ā ū √ and some French and German characters intermixed in both the Java code strings, output to GUIs, and input to forms.  Have searched the internet and help files, but have not found anything that works.

Have unsuccessfully tried using Keyman; have not tried SLP1.
Do not know where in Eclipse or Java to set it up.  Also, do not know how to do a plugin (if that is necessary).

From my Java program, using Eclipse, be able to easily insert special characters in display, print and accept them in input from GUIs.

Comment: lookup eclipse editor and/or console in utf - 8

Comment: Java Strings are Unicode, they can handle these characters without doing anything special.

Comment: But how do I create them in the Java editor in Eclipse?  If I try typing 2 a's to get I get "aa" not ā. (I created the ā using Keyman's character viewer.  Using Keyman is tedious; there are software by which you can do simple keystrokes "aa").  I had such facility on a Windows PC machine before, but do not know how to get it on the Mac.